# Squid3 How store user credentials for specific website?

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a Squid3 Proxy server on my LAN that bridges services to my clients.

Would it be possible for this proxy server to store the credentials that users use to access a specific website? Suppose a user tries to login to login.example.com, how could he store the credentials that my clients use to access that particular website?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. If you think about it and lets assume it was possible to store individuals session/cookies on a proxy server, it will pose a big security threat.

However, what you can store is user authentication as given in the `squid.conf`

```
TAG: authenticate_ttl
#   The time a user & their credentials stay in the logged in
#   user cache since their last request. When the garbage
#   interval passes, all user credentials that have passed their
#   TTL are removed from memory.
#Default:
# authenticate_ttl 1 hour
```